# Need help on Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

Use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to find all solutions to the system of congruences

$$x\equiv 1\pmod 3$$
$$x\equiv3\pmod 5$$
$$x\equiv5\pmod 7$$

Comment: $$x\equiv-2\pmod{[3,5,7]}$$

Comment: See answers to these closely related questions [chinese-remainder-theorem-modular](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1525358/chinese-remainder-theorem-modular) , [the-chinese-remainder-theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363227/the-chinese-remainder-theorem) ,[resolve-a-system-using-chinese-remainder-theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2579603/resolve-a-system-using-chinese-remainder-theorem).

Comment: Here's a subquestion when can't you use constant case ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please don't just post homework questions with no effort shown. Show us what you tried and ask a specific question where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$x+2\equiv0\pmod3$$ $$x+2\equiv0\pmod5$$ $$x+2\equiv0\pmod7$$ A number if divisible by $3$, $5$, $7$ iff it’s divisible by $3\times5\times7=105$. Therefore, we must have $$x+2\in\{105k\mid k\in\mathbb Z\}\Rightarrow$$ $$x\in\{105k-2\mid k\in\mathbb Z\}.$$